# Removing a database engine and create a new one

Tags: sql-server, database, server

2 years ago, we had Corporate version of Kaspersky AV on our server, which installs MS SQL and creates an engine for itself to function properly.

We do not use Kaspersky anymore. Also we have old accounting software stuff in there which we do not use anymore.

I want to delete that engine as I will be creating a new DB for an module I coded for internal company use.

Below is the image for my current scenario inside management studio.

[image: current database scenario]

- How can I remove the KAS_CS admin thing and create a totaly new engine where I can start creating databases inside from scratch?

Any help is appreciated. (In case this is the wrong place to ask the question, please let me know so that I migrate it there)

Comment: That looks like a named instance to me. You could create yourself a new named instance to work with.

Comment: I guess you'll have to install new copy of SQL server and configure it with the desired instance name. Existing installation is configured with KAV_CS_ADMIN instance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your current SQL Server engine is from Version of 2005, which is completely out of date, unsupported and everybody already forgot how to deal with it.
That means you better uninstall it completely: (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143412(v=sql.90).aspx) and install SQL Server 2016.

Comment: Slava, my application is written using SQL 2014, it does work no?

Comment: On your screen shoot it clearly says: SQL Server 9.0.5057, which points to SQL Server Version 2005 SP4 KB#2494120 https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2494120